# App showing only the last set text in notification body

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am studying about Android notifications. I have written a code where I have set different id for intent and also for notification manager. I want the android to show the two different notifications. However, only one notification is showing and only the last set text is showing on the body of the notification.

I have seen some of the same posts, where they mentioned to have a unique id for intent and manager. I have set a unique id for both of them every time I clicked the button however, it still showing one notification with last set text.

My code for mainactivity:

```
private int h;
private int min;
public static int myId = 0;
Calendar c;

public static String notificationHead;
public static String notificationBody;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button picker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    picker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        }
    });

    Button picker1 = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    picker1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });

    Button alarm1 = findViewById(R.id.alarm1);
    alarm1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myId += 1;
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), Integer.toString(myId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notificationHead = "Good Notes Keeper";
            notificationBody = "Take shower";
            startAlarm(c, myId);
        }
    });

    Button alarm2 = findViewById(R.id.alarm2);
    alarm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myId = 2;
            notificationHead = "Good Notes Keeper";
            notificationBody = "Brush teeth";
            startAlarm(c, myId);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
//        c = Calendar.getInstance();
    min = minute;
    h = hourOfDay;
//        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
//        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
//        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
//        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//        startAlarm(c);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

}

private void startAlarm(Calendar c, int id){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

My code for alertreceiver

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper helper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = helper.getChannelNotification();
        helper.getManager().notify(MainActivity.myId, nb.build());
        Log.e("Alert", String.valueOf(MainActivity.myId));
    }
}
```

notificationhelper class

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channelId";

    private NotificationManager mManager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context context){
        super(context);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            createChannel();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel(){
        NotificationChannel channel = new 
NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel1", 
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager(){
        if(mManager == null){
            mManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return mManager;
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification() {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(MainActivity.notificationHead)
            .setContentText(MainActivity.notificationBody)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gnkbw);
    }
}
```

It will be helpful if someone corrects me.

Comment: "I have set different id ... for notification manager." – Not really – `notify(MainActivity.myId, nb.build())`. You're using a `static` field in `MainActivity`. That can end up giving you the same ID a few different ways. Instead, put the ID as an extra on the alarm `Intent` that you create in `startAlarm()`. You can then retrieve it from the `Intent` passed into the `BroadcastReceiver`, and use it in the `notify()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for the comment. I have given a random number on notify method and now it's showing two notification. However, the body of the notification is still showing the last set text for both notifications. https://ibb.co/tYDD5R4

Comment: Well, you're using `static` fields for those, too. In general, it's not a good idea to use `static` fields in non-singleton classes to pass dynamic data. My suggestion for those is the same as for the ID – put them in extras on the alarm `Intent`. And do the same thing for the ID, too, rather than using a random, which is kinda hacky.

Comment: @MikeM. I have retrieved value from edit text and put it in putextra.             `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("body", remindTo.getText().toString());` and I try to get the value in my notification helper class. when I do that, the compiler throwing error as `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference`

Comment: That's not a compilation error. That's a runtime error. I don't know how exactly you're trying to get that extra in `NotificationHelper`, but you should be getting it from the `Intent intent` that's passed into `AlertReceiver`'s `onReceive()`. That won't be null.

Comment: @MikeM. Man, I was dumb previously. Sorry about that. I get a value from intent on `alertreceiver` class and I modified the `Notification` method's `getChannelnotification` to accept a string parameter. Then I passed the value I get from intent as an argument and now it works as expected. You saved my day, Cheers.